# A key combination inserts invisible and festy character in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Xcode inserts an invisible character whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (was trying to save the code but then realised that I am not using Emacs and should use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> instead, and went back to delete the festy character.) Deleting something that is invisible is not fun, so.

Is there a way I can disable this "feature"? And by that I mean make Xcode stop inserting the character and essentially does nothing when I press the key combination. I am not looking for a full Emacs key binding setting for Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in Xcode.

This happens because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> indicates to Xcode that you want to type one of the [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters). The next thing you type tells it which one. Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> inserts an ASCII 19, "device control 3". Different letters insert different control characters-- see the chart at that link for a full list. Control characters are not printable, so it's invisible. Unfortunately Xcode's option to show invisibles (<kbd>Edit</kbd> menu --> <kbd>Invisibles</kbd>) doesn't show ASCII control characters, so you end up with something Xcode doesn't like but that you can't see.

You might be able to use [Karabiner](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements) to deal with this, I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Karabiner is free, but it is a little complicated to add a per-application rule. You need to create an entry for a "Complex Modification" written in JSON, in `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`. See [karabiner.json Reference Manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/json.html)

Another option is [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/). It's not free, but is easier to configure, and has many other features. In the preferences, you would do this:

1. Add Xcode in the application sidebar
2. Click the Keyboard tab
3. Click "Add New Shortcut or Key Sequence"
4. Press control-X in the Shortcut box
5. Leave the "Trigger Predefined Action" at "No Action".

Comment: I'm using BetterTouchTool to enable some Emacs key sequences in XCode, BTW